# Random Number series with a certain range in Java

Tags: java, random

Using the Well512 random number generator class in Java, how can one generate a random number with a range like 0 to 50?

Comment: What does documentation say?

Comment: The WELL512 RNG is a type of random number generator. It is not included in the Java library. There, however, exist implementations in third-party libraries like Apache Commons.

Comment: @Brandon I don't think that covers the WELL512 RNG

Comment: @AndrewRegan if a post isn't a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) many users will downvote it. For that matter, you should also avoid [answering questions have already been asked and answered many times before](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OP has a question about a specific RNG, part of a particular library with a distinct API. I don't know why people seem to have missed/ignored that and assumed he was just a newbie asking about Math.random() and Random, which is what Brandon's link is all about.

Comment: When the answer is "read the JavaDoc", that's a poor question, @AndrewRegan. The first comment also asks "What have you tried yourself", which is another reason this is a poor question. Even if the `nextInt(int)` method didn't exist, a programmer should be capable of trying something himself.

Comment: I think that's harsh, and that Well512 is rare enough (only 9 questions here) for people to not jump on the bandwagon and try to get it closed it down.

Answer (score 0):

For the simplest case (default seed, once only):

```
new org.apache.commons.math3.random.Well512a().nextInt(50);
```

Though you'll doubtless want to store that instance and reuse it.

See: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/random/Well512a.html.

`Well512a` implements https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/random/BitsStreamGenerator.html